# Finding out if a user has a certain role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command !addrole to add a role to a specified user, using discord.js. The code is

```
    //[prefix]roleadd [role]

    if(cmd != `${prefix}roleadd`) return;

    let rAddUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]));
    if(!rAddUser) return message.channel.send('Utente non valido');

    let rAddName = args.join(' ').slice(23);
    if(!rAddName) return message.channel.send('Specifica un ruolo');

    let rAddRole = rAddUser.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === rAddName);
    if(!rAddRole) return message.channel.send('Ruolo non valido');

    if(message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === rAddName))
    return message.channel.send(`A ${rAddUser.user.username}#${rAddUser.user.discriminator} è già stato assegnato il ruolo "${rAddName}"`)


    message.channel.send(`Ruolo "${rAddName}" aggiunto a ${rAddUser.user.username}#${rAddUser.user.discriminator}`);
```

Everything works fine, except for the code that should check if that user already has that particular role. In output it always says that the user already has that role, even if he doesn't actually have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if(message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === rAddName))
```

This is checking wether or not the member that **sends** the message has the role, and if I understand correctly you want to add the role to a member that gets mentioned in the command message instead.

Comment: Yes, I want to check the roles of the mentioned user

Comment: Then you should replace it with if(rAddUser.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === rAddName))